# How do I specify a BeanNamingStrategy with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to specify a custom `BeanNamingStrategy` while configuring my application with Spring Boot. By default, Spring Boot uses the `MethodNameStrategy` which is a `BeanNamingStrategy`.

The reason I want to do this is because I have abstract parent classes which my consumers will create configuration subclasses of. The methods in the parent classes have the same names as each other and so are not getting registered for different implementations of the child classes. My custom `BeanNamingStrategy` will attach the simple name of the configuration class to certain bean names.

Normally in a Spring application you can pass a custom `BeanNamingStrategy` using the `setBeanNamingStrategy` method of the `ApplicationContext`. However if Spring Boot is creating the `ApplicationContext`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SpringApplicationBuilder has a method [`beanNameGenerator()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#beanNameGenerator%28org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator%29) that lets you pass in a custom generator.

See [22.3 Fluent builder API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-fluent-builder-api) in the Spring Boot reference for how to work with the fluent API.

---

Unfortunately this doesn't help you, as this only applies to `@Component`-style class annotations and not to `@Bean` methods, for which the names [are hard coded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d7f8fa50beb5f5e765535e3c4221db6c19893e7b/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java#LC274) using [this method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/f41de12cf62aebf1be9b30be590c12eb2c030853/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/BeanAnnotationHelper.java).

Comment: Thanks, but the `BeanNameGenerator` seems to not be called for `@Bean`-annotated methods (within `@Configuration`-annotated classes), only for `@Component`-annotated classes and for the `@Configuration`-annotated classes themselves. Is there a different object called to generate bean names for methods annotated with `@Bean`?

Comment: @Kidburla that's strange, because the [`ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.html) which is responsible for evaluating `@Configuration` classes clearly is aware of `BeanNameGenerator`: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.html#setBeanNameGenerator-org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator-

Comment: The javadoc you have linked explicitly states "Note that this strategy does *not* apply to `Bean` methods". My understanding was that the `BeanNamingStrategy` was used for `Bean` methods and the `BeanNameGenerator` is only used for resolving beans from annotations at the class-level.

Comment: Looks like the strategy for determining bean names from `Bean` methods is now hard-coded :-( Not sure if there is any way to override this: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod%28org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanMethod%29

Comment: Yeah, just figured as much. Here's the link on Github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/f41de12cf62aebf1be9b30be590c12eb2c030853/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/BeanAnnotationHelper.java

Comment: @Kidburla sounds to me like something you should request as feature

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = ...)` annotation on your main Spring Boot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Beware:** you might have issues w/ `@SpringBootTest` and `@WebMvcTest` using this approach.

If you do run into problems, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054716/componentscan-in-application-class-breaks-webmvctest-and-springboottest) for help/more details.

Comment: Seems like an even better approach is to use `@SpringBootApplication(nameGenerator = ...)` directly, which avoids this issue altogether. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19346) for more details.