# @ComponentScan in application class breaks @WebMvcTest and @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am creating tests with `@WebMvcTest` annotation and found that if I have a `@ComponentScan` annotation in the application class it will break the expected behavior of the tests.

According to the `WebMvcTest` javadoc:

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent Filter`, `WebMvcConfigurer` and `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` beans but not `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` beans)."

The problem is that with `@ComponentScan` it is instantiating beans annotated with `@Service`. If instead of `@ComponentScan` I specify the scan base packages in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation everything works as expected.

Another problem happens when I specify the controller class in the `@WebMvcTest` annotation. When there is a `@ComponentScan` annotation in the application class it will load all controllers instead of loading only the specified one.

Is this a bug in Spring Boot?

I want to use `@ComponentScan` because of the `excludeFilters` attribute which is not available in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

A workaround I have found is to create a separate class with `@Configuration` annotation and move the `@ComponentScan` there.

Answer (score 14):

Found the reason for this odd behavior.

This is the declaration of the @SpringBootApplication annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) })
public @interface SpringBootApplication {
```

As you can see the @ComponentScan annotation inside the @SpringBootApplication has the excludedFilters attribute specified.

When I added the @ComponentScan annotation directly in my application class I did not specify the default excludedFilters and that is why the behavior was different.

Comment: I disagree with the answer. There is also [an ongoing discussion here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10933#issuecomment-342131539).

Comment: This page https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ says "If you directly use @ComponentScan (i.e. not via @SpringBootApplication) you will need to register the TypeExcludeFilter with it.", so I believe the answer is correct.